# Python Classes and inheritance. Calling super method returns Error

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

I have the following python code. The code analyses a digital signal for amplification processing however **I am having trouble applying inheritance concepts to this for some reason**.

**I have a parent class and a child class, which sets the parent class as a parameter to inherit its properties in the child class.**

But **when I try accessing a method within the parent class using OOP inheritance principles I am getting an error**. I originally tried extending the class and not overloading it, but when I tried to access the dofilter() method in the extended parent class, it would throw an error. However, if I try overloading the dofilter() method in the child class and then use "super" to call it from the parent class, there is no error, but returns "NaN", which clearly means I am doing something wrong still. I know data is being passed to the objects, there should be no reason why it returns NaN. It has left me at a little bit of an impass now. **Can anyone please explain why this is not working?**

**What I have tried/my summarized script, to paint a better picture of the issue:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# =============================================================================
# CLASSES
# =============================================================================

class fir_filter:

    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients
        self.buffer = np.zeros(taps)

    def dofilter(self, value, offset): 
        result = 0

        #Splice coefficients and buffer arrays into smaller arrays
        buffer_newest = self.buffer[0:offset+1]
        buffer_oldest = self.buffer[offset+1:taps]
        coefficients1 = self.coefficients[0:offset+1]
        coefficients2 = self.coefficients[offset+1:taps]

        #Accumulate
        self.buffer[offset] = value
        for i in range(len(coefficients1)):
            result += coefficients1[i]*buffer_newest[offset-1-i]
        for i in range(len(coefficients2), 0, -1):
            result += coefficients2[len(coefficients2)-i] * buffer_oldest[i-1]

        return result

class matched_filter(fir_filter):
    def __init__(self,coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients

    def dofilter(self,value,offset):
        super().dofilter(value, offset)

        return result


########################################
#START OF MAIN SCRIPT  
########################################  
#...
#REMOVED- import data files, create vars, perform various calculations.
########################################  


#... RESUME CODE pertinent variables here
m_wavelet = (2/(np.sqrt(3*a*(np.pi**(1/4)))))*(1-((n/a)**2))*np.exp((-n**2)/(2*(a**2)))
m_wavelet = m_wavelet [::-1]
result = np.zeros(l)
offset = 0
plt.figure(6)
plt.plot(m_wavelet)
plt.plot(ecg_3[8100:8800]/len(ecg_3)/300)


########################################  
#instantiated object here, no errors thrown
########################################  
new_filter = matched_filter(m_wavelet)


########################################  
#issue below
######################################## 
for k in range(len(ecg_3)):
    result[k] = new_filter.dofilter(ecg_3[k], offset) #<- Every item in the array is "Nan"
    offset += 1
    if (offset == 2000):
        offset = 0



########################################  
#More removed code/end of script
########################################
```

**Important bits:**

*Parent class:*

```
class fir_filter:

    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients
        self.buffer = np.zeros(taps)

    def dofilter(self, value, offset): 
        result = 0

        #Splice coefficients and buffer arrays into smaller arrays
        buffer_newest = self.buffer[0:offset+1]
        buffer_oldest = self.buffer[offset+1:taps]
        coefficients1 = self.coefficients[0:offset+1]
        coefficients2 = self.coefficients[offset+1:taps]

        #Accumulate
        self.buffer[offset] = value
        for i in range(len(coefficients1)):
            result += coefficients1[i]*buffer_newest[offset-1-i]
        for i in range(len(coefficients2), 0, -1):
            result += coefficients2[len(coefficients2)-i] * buffer_oldest[i-1]

        return result
```

*Child Class:*

```
class matched_filter(fir_filter):
    def __init__(self,coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients

    def dofilter(self,value,offset):
        super().dofilter(value, offset)

        return result
```

*Code and issue:*

```
new_filter = matched_filter(m_wavelet)

for k in range(len(ecg_3)):
    result[k] = new_filter.dofilter(ecg_3[k], offset)
```

**How can I access "dofilter()", in "fir_filter", which is inherited in "matched_filter"?**

Any insight would be much appreciated. I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: You should be getting a `NameError`, as `result` isn't defined in `matched_filter.dofilter`. You could simply write `return super().dofilter(value, offset)`, but if that's all you are doing, there's no reason to override `defilter` in the first place.

Comment: Why does `matched_filter` exist at all? What does it do that `fir_filter` doesn't already do? `matched_filter.__init__` should call `fir_filter.__init__` to ensure that the `buffer` attribute is properly defined, but after you do that, `matched_filter.__init__` doesn't have to do anything else. `matched_filter` is a class that does nothing but delegate *everything* to it parent; it doesn't provide any additional functionality.

Comment: I am required to create a new class, to access that parent class, and utilize dofilter(), through my new child class. Thank you for pointing out the return though, that is much appreciated. You mentioned it would be possible to access dofilter() without overwriting dofilter(). When I tried that it threw an error. What am I doing wrong? How can I access it without overwriting it? Thanks so much for your quick reply!

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is that `child().foo()` can access `parent.foo` even if `child` doesn't define `foo`. Why exactly are you *required* to create a new class if that class doesn't do anything the parent already does?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is part of a larger assignment, where I am required to "create a new class" that utilizes the parent class. I understand that this is redundant.. However I tried to access the parent class directly and it threw an error, which is why I ended up trying to overwrite and call the super method. Can you please outline how I can access it directly so I can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Based on what you have now, `class matched_filter(fir_filter): pass` should suffice.

Comment: If the assignment requires you to write a subclass, but you aren't sure what the subclass should do differently to the parent class, I recommend carefully re-reading the task instructions. It is quite possible you have put everything into the parent class when some of it belongs in the subclass according to the instructions you were given.